# How to organize header/class files in subdirectories in C++ (coming from Java)?

Tags: java, c++, module, namespaces, package

I'm new to C++, coming from Java, and I need to migrate a simple project from Java to C++. I'm confused how to approach modules and class separations in C++. The project is illustrated below. I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) that each class will have to have a header file so it can be imported and used by other systems using my library. But since C++ does not have packages, I'm not sure what's the correct/standard way of approaching that organization problem in C++. Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: The language doesn't define anything like this. It is up to you to decide.

Comment: A decent way would be to convert packages to plain old folders

Comment: @Taelsin And forget about namespaces so when I #include I would just #include with the folder? But then how does someone distribute a library like this?

Comment: If an answer worked for you, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If no one did, add a comment asking for clarification or corrections (if needed).

Answer (score 6):

To keep it simple and clean, yes each class *should* have its own header file and corresponding implementation (.cpp) file. You *can* have more than one class declared per file, nothing prevents you from doing this but if you do maybe you'll spend some time navigating within files to find the class you are looking for (though a "go to definition/declaration" would do the job).

You can create filters in your IDE within your project like you would create packages in Eclipse. I recommend that the filters follow the same folder structure you have in your HDD for you project.

[image: IDE Filters - Folder Structure correlation]

As Glenn said you should use C++ namespaces. For instance, your "Time.java" file would be represented by a "Time.hpp" and a "Time.cpp" file.

**Example:**

Time.hpp:

```
namespace your_project {
  namespace time {
    // Time class declaration
  }
}
```

CpuTime.hpp:

```
namespace your_project {
  namespace time {
    // CpuTime class declaration
  }
}
```

StringUtils.hpp:

```
namespace your_project {
  namespace utils {
    // StringUtils class declaration
  }
}
```

Then if you need to use a class you just include the header.

Example.cpp

```
#include <Utils/StringUtils.hpp>

using namespace your_project::utils;

// Do stuff with StringUtils class
```

Comment: Excellent Ignacio. One more thing. How I would distribute my library? Just compile to a SO file and the folder hierarchy will be preserved inside the SO ???

Comment: Well that's another story and I think that you will find a more complete answer if you search through the posts but to give you some guidance you will need to distribute the header files along with your library. Folder hierarchy will be no more, all that will remain is the namespace hierarchy defined in the library. Since you mentioned "SO" I assume that you are using Linux then it will be easier because you can forget about all the `__declspec(dllexport)` that you need to use in Windows.

Comment: What's the best way to group and distribute my header file? Zip with the folder hierarchy?

Comment: It mainly depends on the size and purpose of your library. Yes you can zip headers with the folder hierarchy (you will want to make a new "header only" structure), you can implement a library interface and distribute only one header. But as I said it is an entire different matter, you will be better off posting a new question with this topic (can't elaborate using 600 characters ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

C++ has namespaces

you can map each directory to a nested namespace

```
namespace myproject
{

   namespace time
   {

   }

}
```